Error while using \cline
for a certain table layout, I am forced to use \cline, but I keep encountering errors and I can't find the cause. 
Existing forum posts that have similar problems could not help me with my problem. 
I got the following error on the \cline Command: Undefined control sequence
Sorry, I have only been working with LaTeX for a short time
\documentclass[sn-mathphys,Numbered]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % Für farbige Zellen
\usepackage{colortbl} % Für das Färben von Zellen in Tabellen
\usepackage{float} % Für die genaue Platzierung der Tabelle im Text
\usepackage{graphicx} % Falls du Grafiken einbinden möchtest
\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{listings}%
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\textbf{Generation}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Faithfulness} \\ \cline{2-2}
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
& \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Answer Relevancy} \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\textbf{Retrieval}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Context Recall} \\ \cline{2-2}
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
& \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Context Precision} \\ \cline{2-2}
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
& \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Context Relevancy} \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\textbf{End-to-end}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Answer Correctness} \\ \cline{2-2}
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
& \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Answer Semantic Similarity} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}


My goal is to generate a table according to the following template:


Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show your first error message in your question: copy it from the log file and past it into your question ...

the class is not a standard one, but if I try your code with the first line \documentclass{article} it runs without error.  Please remove every package not required to show your problem and give a link to the sn-jnl class if that is required

There is no Numbered option in sn-jnl, as far as I can see.
Also, biblatex cannot be used, because the class uses natbib.
Your problem can be solved by

drastically simplifying the input, and
using \hhline instead of \cline.

There is surely no reason for redeclaring the alignment type for every cell. And instead of repeating \rowcolor for every row, you can state \columncolor.
The problem with \multirow is solved by adding the entry at the bottom, with a negative number of rows to spread.
\documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % Für farbige Zellen
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}c|>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l|}
\hline
& Faithfulness \\ \hhline{~|-}
\multirow{-2}{*}{\textbf{Generation}} 
& Answer Relevancy \\ \hline
& Context Recall \\ \hhline{~|-}
& Context Precision \\ \hhline{~|-}
\multirow{-3}{*}{\textbf{Retrieval}}
& Context Relevancy \\ \hline
& Answer Correctness \\ \hhline{~|-}
\multirow{-2}{*}{\textbf{End-to-end}} 
& Answer Semantic Similarity \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}


You might also avoid \columncolor
\documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % Für farbige Zellen
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}% setting local to this center environment
\colorbox[HTML]{EFEFEF}{\begin{tabular}{|c|l|}
\hline
& Faithfulness \\ \hhline{~|-}
\multirow{-2}{*}{\textbf{Generation}}
& Answer Relevancy \\ \hline
& Context Recall \\ \hhline{~|-}
& Context Precision \\ \hhline{~|-}
\multirow{-3}{*}{\textbf{Retrieval}}
& Context Relevancy \\ \hline
& Answer Correctness \\ \hhline{~|-}
\multirow{-2}{*}{\textbf{End-to-end}}
& Answer Semantic Similarity \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{center}

\end{document}

Of course, avoiding vertical rules and \multirow is typographically advised.
\documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % Für farbige Zellen
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}% setting local to this center environment
\colorbox[HTML]{EFEFEF}{%
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
  \toprule
  \textbf{Generation}
    & Faithfulness \\
    & Answer Relevancy \\
  \midrule
  \textbf{Retrieval}
    & Context Recall \\
    & Context Precision \\
    & Context Relevancy \\
  \midrule
  \textbf{End-to-end}
    & Answer Correctness \\
    & Answer Semantic Similarity \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}%
}
\end{center}

\end{document}



With {NiceTabular} of nicematrix.
\documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{NiceTabular}{ll}[hvlines,cell-space-limits=3pt]
  \CodeBefore
    \arraycolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}
  \Body
  \Block{2-1}{Generation}
    & Faithfulness \\
    & Answer Relevancy \\
  \Block{3-1}{Retrieval}
    & Context Recall \\
    & Context Precision \\
    & Context Relevancy \\
  \Block{2-1}{End-to-end}
    & Answer Correctness \\
    & Answer Semantic Similarity \\
  \end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}


